# On 14.04, I ran "openssl genrsa –aes256 -out server-sec.key 4096", but only got Usage prompt, what's wrong?

Tags: openssl

I try to generate server keys, but unable to do so on Ubuntu 14.04, and also unable to understand why it complain about the usage.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Roger

Answer (score 2):

you have a double `--` in front of `aes256`. your exact line with only a single `-` works for me:

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out server-sec.key 4096
```

that's what the help of the command says:

```
$ openssl genrsa  -h
usage: genrsa [args] [numbits]
 -des            encrypt the generated key with DES in cbc mode
 -des3           encrypt the generated key with DES in ede cbc mode (168 bit key)
 -seed
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc seed
 -aes128, -aes192, -aes256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc aes
 -camellia128, -camellia192, -camellia256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc camellia
 -out file       output the key to 'file
 -passout arg    output file pass phrase source
 -f4             use F4 (0x10001) for the E value
 -3              use 3 for the E value
 -engine e       use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
 -rand file:file:...
                 load the file (or the files in the directory) into
                 the random number generator
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a copy from windows caused issue, from screen it's hard to see.

Comment: @wzis so did it work? if so: please accept (and upvote?) the answer. thanks.